# React useContext doesn't update the child component, but works on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I have a navbar component that has a submenu. Once logged in, the submenu of the navbar should change.
I used the hook useContext, but it doesn't refresh the navbar component when the user logs. It works fine when I refresh the page.
Where is my code problem?

APP COMPONENT

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import logo from "./assets/logoBusca.png";
import "./App.css";
import { Route } from "wouter";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Post from "./components/Post";
import NavbarUser from "./components/NavbarUser";
import { AuthContext } from "./context/AuthContext";
import logic from "../src/logic";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const loggedIn = await logic.isUserLoggedIn;
      if (loggedIn) setUser(true);
    })();
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <div className="images">
            <div className="logo">
              <a href="/">
                <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
              </a>
            </div>
            <div className="user_flags">
              <NavbarUser />
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        <Route path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/nuevabusqueda">
          <Post />
        </Route>
      </div>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

NAVBAR COMPONENT

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import userIcon from "../../assets/userIcon.png";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";

export default function NavbarUser() {
  const isAuthenticated = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <>
      {!isAuthenticated ? (
        <div className="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
          <img src={userIcon} alt="user" />
          <div className="navbar-dropdown">
            <a href="/login" className="navbar-item" id="item_login">
              Login
            </a>
            <hr className="navbar-divider" />
            <a href="/registro" className="navbar-item" id="item_register">
              Registro
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
          <img src={userIcon} alt="user" />
          <div className="navbar-dropdown">
            <a href="/datos" className="navbar-item" id="item_login">
              Perfil
            </a>
            <hr className="navbar-divider" />
            <a href="/user" className="navbar-item" id="item_register">
              Logout
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

CONTEXT COMPONENT

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext();
```

LOGIC COMPONENT

```
import buscasosApi from "../data";

const logic = {
  set userToken(token) {
    sessionStorage.userToken = token;
  },

  get userToken() {
    if (sessionStorage.userToken === null) return null;
    if (sessionStorage.userToken === undefined) return undefined;
    return sessionStorage.userToken;
  },

  get isUserLoggedIn() {
    return this.userToken;
  },

  loginUser(email, password) {
    return (async () => {
      try {
        const { token } = await buscasosApi.authenticateUser(email, password);
        this.userToken = token;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
    })();
  },
};
export default logic;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **Login** component doesn't call *setUser(true)*

Here's an example how it might work.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, createContext, useContext } = React;

const AuthContext = createContext();

const Login = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuth] = useContext(AuthContext);
  const onClick = () => setAuth(true);
  return <button disabled={isAuthenticated} onClick={onClick}>Login</button>
}

const App = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated] = useContext(AuthContext);
  
  return <div>
    <Login/>
    <button disabled={!isAuthenticated}>{isAuthenticated ? "Authenticated" : "Not Authenticated"}</button>
  </div>;
}

const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuth] = useState(false);
  
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={[isAuthenticated, setAuth]}>
    {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <AuthProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are not updating state. Initially your state is `false`. After first render, your effect is fired and state is again set to `false`. After that your effect don't run anymore, since it  depends on state that it should change. No state change -  no effect - no state change again. Also, if state will change, it will trigger effect, but you will have no need for this.

Your goal here is to build a system that will:

1. Check current status on load
2. Update (or recheck) status when changed

To do this, you need some way to asynchronously send messages from `logic` to react. You can do this with some kind of subscription, like this:

```js
const logic = {
  set userToken(token) {
    sessionStorage.userToken = token;
  },

  get userToken() {
    if (sessionStorage.userToken === null) return null;
    if (sessionStorage.userToken === undefined) return undefined;
    return sessionStorage.userToken;
  },

  get isUserLoggedIn() {
    return this.userToken;
  },

  loginUser(email, password) {
    return (async () => {
      try {
        const { token } = await buscasosApi.authenticateUser(email, password);
        this.userToken = token;
        this.notify(true);
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
    })();
  },
  subscribers: new Set(),
  subscribe(fn) {
    this.subscribers.add(fn);
    return () => {
      this.subscribers.remove(fn);
    };
  },
  notify(status) {
    this.subscribers.forEach((fn) => fn(status));
  },
};

function useAuthStatus() {
  let [state, setState] = useState("checking");
  let setStatus = useCallback(
    (status) => setState(status ? "authenticated" : "not_authenticated"),
    [setState]
  );
  useEffect(function () {
    return logic.subscribe(setStatus);
  }, []);

  useEffect(function () {
    setStatus(logic.isUserLoggedIn);
  }, []);

  return state;
}
```

Notice, that now there is three possible states - 'checking', 'authenticated' and 'not_authenticated'. It is more detailed and will prevent some errors. For example if you would want to redirect user to login page when they are not authenticated.